# Title for Gridview - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

Can you give the gridview a title?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" style="position:relative; width:80%; left:10%"></asp:GridView>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **`GridView.Caption Property`**   to give `gridview` a title and you can `align` them by using **`GridView.CaptionAlign Property`**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" style="position:relative;
width:80%; left:10%" caption="Customer Information Table"captionalign="Top"  >
</asp:GridView>
```

for more information you can check [microsoft official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.caption?view=netframework-4.8)